# increase size of 2d array and fill with 0

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2d array: for example it's 3x3 array filled with numbers from 1 to 9

array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

And I need to increase its size by 1 and fill them with 0:

array  = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 4, 5, 6], [0, 7, 8, 9],[0, 0, 0, 0]]

I could create a bigger 2d array and put a smaller one in it. But I'd like not to do this

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to just create a bigger array? Don't pre-optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hacky but it works for your use case:

```
array_length = len(array)
for i in range(array_length):
    array[i].insert(0, 0)
array.append([0 for i in array[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, saw this at this site.

[python - increase array size and initialize new elements to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229104/python-increase-array-size-and-initialize-new-elements-to-zero)

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2],[2, 3]])
print(type(A))
print(np.shape(A))
new_shape = (3,4)
shape_diff = np.array(new_shape) - np.array(A.shape)
print("SHape diff =", shape_diff)
new_A= np.lib.pad(A, ((0,shape_diff[0]),(0,shape_diff[1])), 'constant', constant_values=(0))
print(new_A)
```